# Nested Lists in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, list, nested

I am trying to create a nested unordered list using PHP and MySQL (through CodeIgniter, though I don't think that is relevant).

I've seen a number of solutions that appear to work for lists that have two levels of nesting, but the solution I need has to have three levels. This is the sort of thing I need:

```
<ul>
    <li>Top Level, Item 1
        <ul>
            <li>Second Level, Item 1
                <ul>
                    <li>Third Level, Item 1</li>
                    <li>Third Level, Item 2</li>
                    <li>Third Level, Item 3</li>
                </ul>
            <li>Second Level, Item 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Third Level, Item 4</li>
                    <li>Third Level, Item 5</li>
                    <li>Third Level, Item 6</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The output from my database is, essentially:

```
TOP LEVEL | SECOND LEVEL | THIRD LEVEL
Item 1 | Item 1 | Item 1
Item 1 | Item 1 | Item 2
Item 1 | Item 1 | Item 3
Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 4
Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 5
Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 6
```

I've tried going through the output from the database, using variables to register which level I am on etc. but I get into an awful mess with closing off each list.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: what does your database structure and queries look like ?

Comment: Is everything always in threes or does it change?

Comment: @Maximus2012 - My database output is fixed, so there's probably little point in describing that. It outputs something similar to what I've put in the question (obviously with a little more detail!).

Comment: @DevishOne - Yes, it will always be in threes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the assistance, but I think I've cracked it myself, in quite a different way!

The solution provided by @DevishOne got me thinking, and, using that as a bit of a template, I added in variables to identify whether a new sub-list or sub-sub-list should be opened or closed.

I'm not claiming this is foolproof, and neither am I claiming it is particularly efficient, but it does the job for me (so far!)

**My solution:**

```
//Placeholder variables
$current_top = '';
$current_second = '';
$current_third = '';

echo '<ul>';
foreach($array as $row) {
    //If it is a new top level item...
    if ($row['top_level'] != $current_top) {
        //If it isn't the very first top level item...
        if ($current_top != '') {
            //Close off all of the other first, second, and third level branches.
            echo '</ul></li></ul></li>';
        }
        //Echo the top level item, including the start of the sub-list.
        echo '<li>'.$row['top_level'].'<ul>';
        //Set the current top level variable to the current top level item.
        $current_top = $row['top_level'];
        //Set the current second level variable back to null (if it isn't already).
        $current_second = '';
    } 
    //If it is a new second level...
    if ($row['second_level'] != $current_second) {
        //If it isn't the very first second level item...
        if ($current_second != '') {
            //Close off all of the other second and third level branches.
            echo '</ul></li>';
        }
        //Echo the second level item, including the start of the sub-sub-list.
        echo '<li>'.$row['second_level'].'<ul>';
        //Set the current second level variable to the current second level item.
        $current_second = $row['second_level'];
        //Set the current third level variable back to null (if it isn't already).
        $current_third = '';
    } 
    //If it is a new third level...
    if ($row['third_level'] != $current_third) {
        //Echo the third level item, and close it off.
        echo '<li>'.$row['third_level'].'</li>';
        //Set the current third level variable to the current third level item.
        $current_third = $row['third_level'];
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**query**

```
SELECT a.item, b.item, c.item FROM TOP_LEVEL a JOIN SECOND_LEVEL b ON b.level = a.level JOIN THIRD_LEVEL c ON c.level = b.level ORDER BY a.item, b.item, c.item
```

**code**

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT a.item, b.item, c.item FROM TOP_LEVEL a JOIN SECOND_LEVEL b ON b.level = a.level JOIN THIRD_LEVEL c ON c.level = b.level ORDER BY a.item, b.item, c.item ";
...... your database stuff......
...... resulting array should be two-dimensional `$items` ......
$c = 0;
echo "<ul>\n";
while ($c < count($items)) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($items[$c][0]); $j++) {
        echo "<li>$items[$c][0]\n";
        echo "<ul>\n";
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($items[$c][1]); $k++) {
            echo "<li>$items[$c][1]\n";
            echo "<ul>\n";
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($items[$c][2]); $i++) {
                echo "<li>$items[$c][2]<\li>\n";
                $c++;
            }
            echo "</ul>\n";
            echo "</li>\n";
                    $c++;
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
        echo "</li>\n";
            $c++;
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained more clearly - it is not the SQL that I am after. I already have that, and it is pretty fixed. It is the processing of the SQL query results to turn it into a 3-level nested unordered list in HTML.

Comment: Are you using mysqli or PDO?

Comment: That should do it for you.

Comment: Oh, sorry again, when I said it was always in threes, I meant there would always be something from each column - an item, sub-item, and a sub-sub-item.

There could actually be varying amounts of each one (e.g. one item, 3 sub-items, and 5 sub-items, or whatever). Sorry! (Oh, and I'm using whatever db drivers are built into CodeIgniter...)

Comment: I don't use CodeIgniter, so you're on your own there but the rest of it is written out for you. Enjoy.

Comment: That looks like just what I'm after! I shall try it out in the morning and report back. Many thanks!

Comment: It's getting there, but I've run into some more problems... I'd like it to only display an item once for all of the sub-items beneath it. It is currently displaying each item and each sub-item for each row of the table.