# Nested JSON data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, nested

I recently posted this question ([Nested Lists in PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063291/nested-lists-in-php-and-mysql)) about how to create a nested unordered list using PHP and MySQL.

With some assistance, I actually managed to solve this myself (in a no doubt convoluted and inefficient manner - see the solution).

Now, I need exactly the same nested structure from MySQL, but in JSON.

Could anyone tell me how to do this?

I was planning to construct a multidimensional array and then convert that to JSON with `json_encode`. Should I reuse the `foreach` structure I used to solve my previous problem or is there an easier way (given that I don't have to worry about closing off lists and sub-lists etc.)?

Comment: In case if you need it on a client side, you could get json with javascript from a formed tree too.

Answer (score 0):

json_encode is obviously the better way than your previous solution. 
An example would be like this, perhaps

```
$mainarray = array();

foreach($items as $k => $v)
{
   array_push($v,$mainarray);
}
echo json_encode($mainarray);
```